# как сменить Qt.ItemIsAutoTristate на Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable во всех элементах дерева qtreewidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5

Имеется дерево `qtreewidget` с разным уровнем потомков и количеством узлов. При его построении для каждого элемента создается флажок для его выбора с флагом элемента `Qt.ItemIsAutoTristate`. Так же имеются две radiobutton по переключению которых вызывается метод `rechecking()` для переопределения флагов у каждого элемента дерева, например чтобы сменить на `Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable` или обратно. Это нужно для удобства выбора флажков: чтобы можно было выделить родителя и кучу его потомков одним кликом, а потом снять выделение только с родителя и при снятии флажков с потомков состояние родителя не изменялось бы.
Так вот этот метод отрабатывает, однако понятно что при этом ничего не изменяется, выбор флажков остается всегда как при `Qt.ItemIsAutoTristate`, то есть на `Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable` не изменяется.
Куда копать не пойму.

Вот минимальный код для проверки:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class TreeViewDemo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TreeViewDemo, self).__init__()

        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox()
        self.groupBox.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 90))
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.radioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 150, 25))
        self.radioButton.setChecked(True)
        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.radioButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 50, 150, 25))
        self.radioButton.setText("Множественный выбор")
        self.radioButton_2.setText("Единичный выбор")

        self.treeWidget = QTreeWidget()
        self.treeWidget.setColumnCount(1)
        self.treeWidget.setHeaderLabels(['Items'])

        for i in range(3):
            parent = QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
            parent.setText(0, f'Item {i}')
            flags = parent.flags() | Qt.ItemIsAutoTristate
            parent.setFlags(flags)
            parent.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
            self.treeWidget.addTopLevelItem(parent)

        self.add_child_button = QPushButton('Add Child')
        self.add_child_button.clicked.connect(self.add_child)

        self.radioButton.clicked.connect(self.rechecking)
        self.radioButton_2.clicked.connect(self.rechecking)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.treeWidget)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.add_child_button)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.groupBox)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def add_child(self):
        selected_item = self.treeWidget.currentItem()
        child = QTreeWidgetItem()
        child.setText(0, 'Child Item')
        flags = child.flags() | Qt.ItemIsAutoTristate
        child.setFlags(flags)
        child.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        selected_item.addChild(child)

    def rechecking(self):

        def recurse(parent_item):
            for i in range(parent_item.childCount()):
                child = parent_item.child(i)
                grand_children = child.childCount()

                if self.radioButton.isChecked():
                    print('кнопка 1')
                    flags = Qt.ItemIsAutoTristate
                    if grand_children > 0:
                        child.setFlags(child.flags() | flags)
                        recurse(child)
                    child.setFlags(child.flags() | flags)

                if self.radioButton_2.isChecked():
                    print('кнопка 2')
                    flags = Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable
                    if grand_children > 0:
                        child.setFlags(child.flags() | flags)
                        recurse(child)
                    child.setFlags(child.flags() | flags)

                child.setFlags(child.flags() | flags)
            parent_item.setFlags(parent_item.flags() | flags)

        recurse(self.treeWidget.invisibleRootItem())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = TreeViewDemo()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: manool, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Я  так понимаю, отредактировали из-под другого аккаунта

Comment: Пишу в ответе, т.к. репы еще недостаточно для комментариев. @NowhereMan, это странно, но да, правки в вопрос делал я и вопрос этот мой, просто задал я его без регистрации, а потом регистрацию продолжил по ссылке из почты и вот теперь я - другой пользователь.

Comment: На всякий случай тут продублирую: [Я случайно создал две учётные записи, как их объединить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 0):

В итоге не стал заморачиваться, сделал проще: организовал все через контекстное меню, сделал в нем два пункта : "`Выбрать всю ветку`" и "`Снять выделение`". А по умолчанию построение дерева сделал с флагом `Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable`. Теперь можно клюкнуть по любому родительскому элементу и через контекстное меню установить состояние флажков всех потомков.